# How do I check to see if two (or more) elements of an array/vector are the same?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, element

For one of my homework problems, we had to write a function that creates an array containing n random numbers between 1 and 365. (Done). Then, check if any of these `n` birthdays are identical. Is there a shorter way to do this than doing several loops or several logical expressions?

Thank you!

CODE SO FAR, NOT DONE YET!!

```
 function = [prob] bdayprob(N,n)
 N = input('Please enter the number of experiments performed: N = ');
 n = input('Please enter the sample size: n = ');
 count = 0;

 for(i=1:n)
   x(i) = randi(365);
   if(x(i)== x)
     count = count + 1
 end

return
```

Comment: Share your code, use sample input data and explain the expected output with them?

Comment: @Divikar Okay, will do

Comment: Your function doesn't make much sense unfortunately.  `N` and `n` are inputs into your function, yet you overwrite these values by requesting them from the user interactively (through `input`).  Also, `prob` is the output variable but it's not referenced in the code.  What is `prob` supposed to be?  What are you supposed to do when you figure out that the birthdays are not unique for a trial?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question properly, you want to check to see if generating `n` integers or days results in `n` **unique** numbers.  Given your current knowledge in MATLAB, it's as simple as doing:

```
n = 30; %// Define sample size
N = 10; %// Define number of trials

%// Define logical array where each location tells you whether 
%// birthdays were repeated for a trial
check = false(1, N);

%// For each trial...
for idx = 1 : N
    %// Generate sample size random numbers
    days = randi(365, n, 1);

    %// Check to see if the total number of unique birthdays 
    %// are equal to the sample size
    check(idx) = numel(unique(days)) == n;
end
```

Woah!  Let's go through the code slowly shall we?  We first define the sample size and the number of trials.  We then specify a `logical` array where each location tells you whether or not there were repeated birthdays generated for that trial.  Now, we start with a loop where for each trial, we generate random numbers from 1 to 365 that is of `n` or sample size long.  We then use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and figure out all **unique** integers that were generated from this random generation.  If all of the birthdays are unique, then the total number of unique birthdays generated should **equal the sample size**.  If we don't, then we have repeats.  For example, if we generated a sample of `[1 1 1 2 2]`, the output of `unique` would be `[1 2]`, and the total number of unique elements is 2.  Since this **doesn't** equal 5 or the sample size, then we know that the birthdays generated weren't unique.  However, if we had `[1 3 4 6 7]`, `unique` would give the same output, and since the output length is the same as the sample size, we know that all of the days are unique.

So, we check to see if this number is equal to the sample size for each iteration.  If it is, then we output `true`.  If not, we output `false`.  When I run this code on my end, this is what I get for `check`.  I set the sample size to 30 and the number of trials to be 10.

```
check =

     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Take note that if you increase the sample size, there is a higher probability that you will get duplicates, because `randi` can be considered as sampling with replacement.  Therefore, the larger the sample size, the higher the chance of getting duplicate values.  I made the sample size small on purpose so that we can see that it's possible to get unique days.  However, if you set it to something like 100, or 200, you will most likely get `check` to be all `false` as there will most likely be duplicates per trial.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more approaches that avoid loops. Let

```
n = 20; %// define sample size
x = randi(365,n,1); %// generate n values between 1 and 365
```

Any of the following code snippets returns `true` (or `1`) if there are two identical values in `x`, and `false` (or `0`) otherwise:

- Sort and then check if any two consecutive elements are the same:

  ```
  result = any(diff(sort(x))==0);
  ```
- Do all pairwise comparisons manually; remove self-pairs and duplicate pairs; and check if any of the remaining comparisons is true:

  ```
  result = nnz(tril(bsxfun(@eq, x, x.'),-1))>0;
  ```
- Compute the distance between distinct values, considering each pair just once, and then check if any distance is `0`:

  ```
  result = any(pdist(x(:))==0);
  ```
- Find the number of occurrences of the most common value (mode):

  ```
  [~, occurs] = mode(x);
  result = occurs>1;
  ```

Comment: Very nice alternatives. +1.  I particularly like the use of `mode`.  Ingenious really.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! After your very nice answer and explanation, only more-or-less-exotic alternatives were left :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm supposed to solve the problem for you, but perhaps a few hints may lead you in the right direction (besides I'm not a matlab expert so it will be in general terms):

Maybe not, but you have to ask yourself what they expect of you. The solution you propose requires you to loop through the array in two nested loops which will mean n*(n-1)/2 times through the loop (ie quadratic time complexity).

There are a number of ways you can improve the time complexity of the problem. The most straightforward would be to have a 365 element table where you can keep track if a particular number has been seen yet - which would require only a single loop (ie linear time complexity), but perhaps that's not what they're looking for either. But maybe that solution is a little bit ad-hoc? What we're basically looking for is a fast lookup if a particular number has been seen before - there exists more memory efficient structures that allows look up in O(1) time and O(log n) time (if you know these you have an arsenal of tools to use).

Then of course you could use the pidgeonhole principle to provide the answer much faster in some special cases (remember that you only asked to determine whether two or more numbers are equal or not).